# Google Pie Charts não é exibido quando os dados tem mais de um row

Tags: php, javascript, json, google-charts

estou tentando exibir um PieChart, porém, se a pesquisa no banco retorna somente uma linha, o gráfico é exibido. Se retorna mais de uma linha, o gráfico não aparece.

funcao que gera os dados do gráfico:

```
public function grpAplicacaoRecursos() {
// Estrutura basica do grafico
    $grafico = array(
        'dados' => array(
            'cols' => array(
                array('type' => 'string', 'label' => 'Descricao'),
                array('type' => 'number', 'label' => 'Valor')
            ),
            'rows' => array()
        ),
        'config' => array(
            'title' => 'Para onde vai meu dinheiro',
            'width' => 400,
            'height' => 250
        )
    );

    $dataAtual = new DateTime('now');
    $inicioUltimaSemana = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dataAtual->format('Y-m-d').' -365 days'));


    $dados = $this->registry->conn->fetchAll('SELECT c.descricao descricao, sum(m.valor) valor '.
            'FROM movimento_conta m left join conta c on m.conta_id = c.conta_id where m.data '.
            'between ? and ? group by descricao ', array($inicioUltimaSemana, $dataAtual->format('Y-m-d')));

    foreach ($dados as $row) {
        $grafico['dados']['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
                array('v' => $row['descricao']),
                array('v' => $row['valor'])
        ));
    }
    // Enviar dados na forma de JSON
    header( 'Cache-Control: no-cache' );
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    echo json_encode($grafico);
}
```

retorno da função:

```
{  
"dados":{  
  "cols":[  
     {  
        "type":"string",
        "label":"Descricao"
     },
     {  
        "type":"number",
        "label":"Valor"
     }
  ],
  "rows":[  
     {  
        "c":[  
           {  
              "v":"teste1"
           },
           {  
              "v":"554.890"
           }
        ]
     },
     {  
        "c":[  
           {  
              "v":"teste2"
           },
           {  
              "v":"2556.000"
           }
        ]
     }
  ]
},
"config":{  
  "title":"Para onde vai meu dinheiro",
  "width":400,
  "height":250
}
}
```

script na página que exibe o grafico:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var json_text = $.ajax({url: "/index/grpAplicacaoRecursos", dataType: "json", async: false}).responseText;
    var json = eval("(" + json_text + ")");
    var dados = new google.visualization.DataTable(json.dados);

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('area_grafico2'));
    chart.draw(dados, json.config);
});


</script>
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado ?

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

Por acaso você esperava ver algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se for, é bem simples de resolver apesar de não ser lá muito óbvio: Seus valores decimais não decimais, são strings numéricas.

Muito provavelmente a culpa é da forma como o Google Charts interpreta a informação do JSON informado.

Se eu tivesse que adivinhar diria que por você estar definindo um **type** como **number** mas estar passando uma **string**, quando esse valor é convertido para número da regra que você definiu, deve resultar em algum valor inesperado.

Remova as aspas dos valores forçando o cast da variável para float e o gráfico deve aparece (**deve** porque eu modifiquei o JSON manualmente):

```
foreach ($dados as $row) {
    $grafico['dados']['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
        array('v' => $row['descricao']),
        array('v' => (float) $row['valor'])
    ));
}
```

Desprezar os zeros à direita da casa decimal também faz o gráfico aparecer, mesmo sem alterar o tipo da variável, mas os resultados que obtive foram diferentes.